# In Highcharts, for a 3D chart, are we able to set up labels of the z-axis?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

What I am looking for is something like this:
[image]

In Highcharts, column type doesn't offer a z-axis at all:
https://jsfiddle.net/scottszb1987/334gruzf/

And scatter type does have a z-axis, but you cannot change the labels by adding `categories`
https://jsfiddle.net/scottszb1987/kxafwcas/

So, i'm wondering, first, are we able to enable z-axis labels to a 3D column chart, second, are we able to modify z-axis labels to strings in 3D scatter chart?

Comment: I think that you can get zAxis in column chart. Look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/169u3awk/1/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński Actualy you are right man, thanks a lot. If you leave an answer down there, i'll make it the right answer.

Comment: Happy to read that my example worked for you. I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it is possible to have zAxis with categories in column chart. I have made an example showing how you can make this axis:

```
zAxis: {
  min: 0,
  max: 1,
  categories: ['one', 'two'],
},
```

Here you can find live example of making zAxis with categories in column chart:
https://jsfiddle.net/169u3awk/1/

Regards,